# Google Cloud BigTable - slow response time from outside of Google Project

Tags: oauth, throughput, google-cloud-bigtable

When all the code is running in a Google Project; performance is as expected.

However; during development, I connect my laptop to a test Google Project BigTable instance; and each query takes 2-4 seconds to run.

Its a similar response response when I trigger commands using `cbt` CLI commands.

Is there a known reason for this overhead? Perhaps its how auth needs to be done for external connections?

On start up I see the below logs:

```
 Opening connection for projectId ..., instanceId ..., on data host bigtable.googleapis.com, admin host bigtableadmin.googleapis.com.
 Bigtable options: BigtableOptions{dataHost=bigtable.googleapis.com, adminHost=bigtableadmin.googleapis.com, ..., appProfileId=, userAgent=hbase-1.4.1, credentialType=DefaultCredentials, port=443, dataChannelCount=32, retryOptions=RetryOptions{retriesEnabled=true, allowRetriesWithoutTimestamp=false, statusToRetryOn=[DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, UNAVAILABLE, UNAUTHENTICATED, ABORTED], initialBackoffMillis=5, maxElapsedBackoffMillis=60000, backoffMultiplier=2.0, streamingBufferSize=60, readPartialRowTimeoutMillis=60000, maxScanTimeoutRetries=3}, bulkOptions=BulkOptions{asyncMutatorCount=2, useBulkApi=true, bulkMaxKeyCount=125, bulkMaxRequestSize=1048576, autoflushMs=0, maxInflightRpcs=320, maxMemory=143183052, enableBulkMutationThrottling=false, bulkMutationRpcTargetMs=100}, callOptionsConfig=CallOptionsConfig{useTimeout=false, shortRpcTimeoutMs=60000, longRpcTimeoutMs=600000}, usePlaintextNegotiation=false}.
 Refreshing the OAuth token
```

Are there any options I can consider; other than using the BitTable emulator? I had some trouble getting that running a while back; so must try again.

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: This seems like a service issue, and is not something that is diagnosable via stack overflow.  Would you be able to raise a Google Cloud support ticket to figure this out?

Comment: @brent were you able to raise a ticket for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As Solomon said above, please open a Google Cloud support ticket to resolve this.